# Difference between block and block size in Advanced Unix

Tags: unix

I want clear difference between the block and block size and how the stat function assign
the value of the block and block size.

```
$ stat 15*10.txt
 File: `15*10.txt'
  Size: 1914        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 302792      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1001/ hussain)   Gid: ( 1001/ hussain)
Access: 2013-10-19 19:13:53.863927172 +0530
Modify: 2013-10-18 15:25:59.109467143 +0530
Change: 2013-10-19 13:05:34.031996517 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

```
 man fstat
```

which reports:

- The blocks  field  indicates  the number of blocks allocated to the file, 512-byte units.
- The blocksize field gives the "preferred" blocksize for efficient file system I/O.

Comment: Hmm! I saw the man page for the fstat, but i cant understand it how it allocates the block size. every file has same block size. How to identify it.